# Android: How to make multiple CountdownTimers work on background?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have an App where the user can create multiple countdown alarms. Each one has it's own name, time to count, ringtone, etc.

I extended the CountDownTimer to hold each alarm setup and created a Singleton manager to manage all the alarms.

Everything is working fine until I leave the App.

The counters don't actually die. They have a weird behavior. After starting a counter:
1) if I press back key until the home screen and then power off the screen the alarm will trigger as it should.
2) if I press the home button then turn off the screen it will trigger only if I open the app.
3) if I just turn off the screen while still on the app it will trigger as soon as I turn on the screen. 
I expected trouble because for that kind of thing I need to use Services, Handlers or other stuff like these.

The problem is, I'm new to Android and after reading a lot about it, I couldn't find a solution.

As far as I understood I should use Services, but it can have only one instance. How would I work with multiple alarms?

Is there other way of doing it?

I need a way to start each alarm and tell the system to keep counting no matter what happens! (and to call an Activity when it finishes)

Any help?

Comment: work with one CountDownTImer, the alarms would be at different times, everytime the count down timer is compeleted, check the next alarm available and start the countdowntimer for the next alarm.

Comment: Every alarm is different from each other and they must run simultaneously or not. It's up to the user when to start/stop each. Also, it wouldn't solve my problem anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there other way of doing it?

If your goal is to alert the user of events in the future, regardless of whether your app is running, dump all your `CountdownTimer` logic, and switch to `AlarmManager`. It is specifically designed for this sort of scenario. You can set up an `AlarmManager` event for each timer, to get control when the end time is reached.

Also note that you will need to maintain information about your registered events in a file or database:

- so users can add and remove them, and
- so you can set up `AlarmManager` again if the user reboots their device

> and to call an Activity when it finishes

Users may reject your app for that behavior. Not everyone wants to be interrupted in the middle of what they are doing with their device. Please allow this to be configurable, so the user can opt for something less intrusive, like a `Notification`.

Comment: They are simple countdown timers. I need to show a ticking clock for each one and if the user goes away from the timers or app they have to keep running and warn the user when it finishes. (and if the user gets back to the timers, they need to keep ticking). Correct me if I'm wrong but AlarmManager seems to be for scheduling background operations and I can't "tick" the clocks with it. I need visual countdown timers that warns the user if it expires when he's not looking.

Comment: The counters don't actually die. They have a weird behavior. After starting a counter 1) if I press back key until the home screen and then power off the screen the alarm will trigger as it should. 2) if I press the home button then turn off the screen it will trigger only if I open the app. 3) if I just turn off the screen while still on the app it will trigger as soon as I turn on the screen.

Comment: @Dpedrinha if you want to check if they really dont die, then start opening heavy applications like: camera (do some photos), then open webbrowser (open few tabs with sites), then open PDF viewer, then maybe Kindle (if you use it), do some phone calls, .... Your app eventually will be killed, but... if it is really very small then android might prolong its life - to write reliable apps you must obey system rules which are simple, `be prepared for your app to be killed any time`

Comment: @Dpedrinha: You use `AlarmManager` for the "warns the user if it expires when he's not looking" part. What you do while your activity is in the foreground is up to you.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. Having countdown timers to tick the clocks and an alarm set for each. But I can't believe that's the only way. It's too ugly. That's why I was thinking in a way to put this process in a high priority.. Thanks

Comment: @Dpedrinha: "That's why I was thinking in a way to put this process in a high priority" -- first, it is not reliable. Second, it is inefficient, as it wastes CPU and battery. If you are not in the foreground, *your process does not need to exist*. Time will continue flowing even if your process is not around to monitor it.

Comment: @Dperdinha - you are arguing with well know pattern. If activity is not in foreground (visible) it can be killed by system at any single moment. If your phone decreases power level all processes can be hibernated. If you use powerlocks (however I'm really afraid mention it) user will uninstall your application in order to battery draining issue. And you are trying to solve really simple problem using strange (and wrong) workarounds, instead of putting ~50 lines of the right code.

Comment: I'm not arguing. As I said, I'm new to Android and it's architecture. I'm used to develop web apps, so battery was never a predicted problem by the OS. I'm just trying to understand it. Thanks for clearing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your CountdownTimers with `AlarmManager` (as in CommonsWare's answer), after setting it up it will trigger your function to execute on specified time, here is official guide:

http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Soon you will find that after device reboot your alarms are lost, you need to restart them by catching `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast.

Also you should not do a lot of work in your alarm onReceive, you should pass information to some other component like `IntentService`, to make it safe while device is asleep you should use `WakeLock` ([sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast)).

[edit] ---- you should also store your alarm/ringtone related data in some persistant storage, you can use for it shared preferences, or (more work) sqlite database.

Comment: As in Android Reference: Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler. 
My scenario is different. They are simple visual countdown clocks that ticks and warns the user if he is outside the app. Also, after kitkat, AlarmManager will be inexact. And they need to be trust worthy in my case.

Comment: @Dpedrinha Simply, your CountDownTimer will be destroyed once you leave your app and start surfing web. This might not happen immediately. As for KitKat, I found following excerpt in AlarmManager docs, `" There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent)."`.

Answer (score 0):

I you really want to use timer (i.e. when you want to show countdowns on screen):
You **don't have to have multiple timers** to show multiple countdowns.

Everything you have to do is just put the target time into some collection, or event put it into the View.setTag().

Then you have timer (let say 1s tick) - on every single tick you have to iterate over all your gauges, check the target time and current time, parse the number and adjust the gauge.

However - as the timers works on separate (non main) threads - you will have to use handler or something like that.
If you want to just set some alarms - take the CommonsWare's answer - it's good one.

Comment: The problem is that this does not solve the core issue: "Everything is working fine until I leave the App". Once the app is not in the foreground, the process can be terminated at any time, taking the `CountdownTimer` instances with it.

Comment: You are right - putting a IntentService with the simple getNearestAlarm() method inside it will be better. On the other hand, I'm still surprised how fancy methods people could find just to not read about some basic Android components.

Comment: I believe this approach would be too complicated for my scenario. Maybe I'm not being clear. It's a typical set of countdown clocks. The user can create as many countdown timers as he wants. He can set up different duration and ringtones for each one. He needs to see the remaining time for each one and be able to start, pause, continue and reset anyone whenever he wants. And it must ring with a "stop ringing" button when each timer finishes even if the screen is off or if another activity is on top.